# SwiftUI - Random number generator freezing when blackjack button is pressed multiple times

Tags: swift, button, random, swiftui, conditional-statements

I am creating a standard blackjack training program that has conditional statements to determine whether a user should "Hit" "Stand" "Double" or "Split" when provided 2 random cards against a dealers card. If the user is correct, it will display "correct" and change the background color to green - the opposite is true if incorrect (red/incorrect). The conditionals and random number generator are included in each button's action code. The random number generator will work perfectly as long as I switch between the buttons but when I press the same button multiple times and it produces the same answer as before, it will no longer generate a random number. I won't paste it all, but I have 4 corresponding buttons will the same code as displayed below. In addition to fixing the random number generator issue, I am open to all critique on improving my code below (I'm brand new).

```
    @State private var correctAnswer: String = ""
    @State private var hitButton: String = "HIT"
    @State private var standButton: String = "STAND"
    @State private var doubleButton: String = "DOUBLE"
    @State private var splitButton: String = "SPLIT"
    @State private var youAnswer: String = ""
    @State private var noteOfAdvice: String = ""
    @State private var randomYouCard1: String = ""
    @State private var randomYouCard2: String = ""
    @State private var randomDealerCard: String = ""
    
    var correctColor: Color {
        return youAnswer == correctAnswer ? Color.green : Color.red
    }
    
    var correctTitle: String {
        return youAnswer == correctAnswer ? "correct" : "incorrect"
    }
    
    let cardArray = ["2.01", "2.02", "2.03", "2.04", "3.01", "3.02", "3.03", "3.04", "4.01", "4.02", "4.03", "4.04", "5.01", "5.02", "5.03", "5.04", "6.01", "6.02", "6.03", "6.04", "7.01", "7.02", "7.03", "7.04", "8.01", "8.02", "8.03", "8.04", "9.01", "9.02", "9.03", "9.04", "10.01", "10.02", "10.03", "10.04", "10.05", "10.06", "10.07", "10.08", "10.09", "10.010", "10.011", "10.012", "10.013", "10.014", "10.015", "10.016"]

    var body: some View {

        var randomYouCard1 = cardArray.randomElement()!
        var randomYouCard2 = cardArray.randomElement()!
        var randomDealerCard = cardArray.randomElement()!
        let clippedYouCard1 = randomYouCard1.components(separatedBy: ".")
        let clippedYouCard2 = randomYouCard2.components(separatedBy: ".")
        let clippedDealerCurrentCard: [String] = randomDealerCard.components(separatedBy: ".")

        Button(action: {
                        
                        
                        youAnswer = standButton
                        
                        
                        if clippedYouCard1[0] == clippedYouCard2[0] && clippedYouCard1[0] == "2" {
                            let twoSplit: [String] = ["7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2"]
                            if twoSplit.contains(clippedDealerCurrentCard[0]) {
                                    correctAnswer = "SPLIT"
                                } else {
                                    correctAnswer = "HIT"
                                }
                        } else if clippedYouCard1[0] == clippedYouCard2[0] && clippedYouCard1[0] == "3" {
                            let threeSplit: [String] = ["7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2"]
                            if threeSplit.contains(clippedDealerCurrentCard[0]) {
                                    correctAnswer = "SPLIT"
                                } else {
                                    correctAnswer = "HIT"
                                }
                        } else if clippedYouCard1[0] == clippedYouCard2[0] && clippedYouCard1[0] == "4" {
                            let fourSplit: [String] = ["6", "5"]
                            if fourSplit.contains(clippedDealerCurrentCard[0]) {
                                    correctAnswer = "SPLIT"
                                } else {
                                    correctAnswer = "HIT"
                                }
                        } else if clippedYouCard1[0] == clippedYouCard2[0] && clippedYouCard1[0] == "5" {
                            let fiveHit: [String] = ["10", "11"]
                            if fiveHit.contains(clippedDealerCurrentCard[0]) {
                                    correctAnswer = "HIT"
                                } else {
                                    correctAnswer = "DOUBLE"
                                }
                        } else if clippedYouCard1[0] == clippedYouCard2[0] && clippedYouCard1[0] == "6" {
                            let sixSplit: [String] = ["6", "5", "4", "3", "2"]
                            if sixSplit.contains(clippedDealerCurrentCard[0]) {
                                    correctAnswer = "SPLIT"
                                } else {
                                    correctAnswer = "HIT"
                                }
                        } else if clippedYouCard1[0] == clippedYouCard2[0] && clippedYouCard1[0] == "7" {
                            let sevenSplit: [String] = ["7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2"]
                            if sevenSplit.contains(clippedDealerCurrentCard[0]) {
                                    correctAnswer = "SPLIT"
                                } else {
                                    correctAnswer = "HIT"
                                }
                        } else if clippedYouCard1[0] == clippedYouCard2[0] && clippedYouCard1[0] == "8" {
                            correctAnswer = "SPLIT"
                        } else if clippedYouCard1[0] == clippedYouCard2[0] && clippedYouCard1[0] == "9" {
                            let nineStand: [String] = ["7", "10", "11"]
                            if nineStand.contains(clippedDealerCurrentCard[0]) {
                                    correctAnswer = "STAND"
                                } else {
                                    correctAnswer = "SPLIT"
                                }
                        } else if clippedYouCard1[0] == clippedYouCard2[0] && clippedYouCard1[0] == "10" {
                            correctAnswer = "STAND"
                        } else if clippedYouCard1[0] == clippedYouCard2[0] && clippedYouCard1[0] == "11" {
                            correctAnswer = "SPLIT"
                        } else if (clippedYouCard1[0] == "11" || clippedYouCard2[0] == "11") && (clippedYouCard1[0] == "2" || clippedYouCard2[0] == "2") {
                            let aceTwoDouble: [String] = ["5", "6"]
                            if aceTwoDouble.contains(clippedDealerCurrentCard[0]) {
                                correctAnswer = "DOUBLE"
                            } else {
                                correctAnswer = "HIT"
                            }
                        } else if (clippedYouCard1[0] == "11" || clippedYouCard2[0] == "11") && (clippedYouCard1[0] == "3" || clippedYouCard2[0] == "3") {
                            let aceThreeDouble: [String] = ["5", "6"]
                            if aceThreeDouble.contains(clippedDealerCurrentCard[0]) {
                                correctAnswer = "DOUBLE"
                            } else {
                                correctAnswer = "HIT"
                            }
                        } else if (clippedYouCard1[0] == "11" || clippedYouCard2[0] == "11") && (clippedYouCard1[0] == "4" || clippedYouCard2[0] == "4") {
                            let aceFourDouble: [String] = ["4", "5", "6"]
                            if aceFourDouble.contains(clippedDealerCurrentCard[0]) {
                                correctAnswer = "DOUBLE"
                            } else {
                                correctAnswer = "HIT"
                            }
                        } else if (clippedYouCard1[0] == "11" || clippedYouCard2[0] == "11") && (clippedYouCard1[0] == "5" || clippedYouCard2[0] == "5") {
                            let aceFiveDouble: [String] = ["4", "5", "6"]
                            if aceFiveDouble.contains(clippedDealerCurrentCard[0]) {
                                correctAnswer = "DOUBLE"
                            } else {
                                correctAnswer = "HIT"
                            }
                        } else if (clippedYouCard1[0] == "11" || clippedYouCard2[0] == "11") && (clippedYouCard1[0] == "6" || clippedYouCard2[0] == "6") {
                            let aceSixDouble: [String] = ["3", "4", "5", "6"]
                            if aceSixDouble.contains(clippedDealerCurrentCard[0]) {
                                correctAnswer = "DOUBLE"
                            } else {
                                correctAnswer = "HIT"
                            }
                        } else if (clippedYouCard1[0] == "11" || clippedYouCard2[0] == "11") && (clippedYouCard1[0] == "7" || clippedYouCard2[0] == "7") {
                            let aceSevenStand: [String] = ["7", "8"]
                            let aceSevenHit: [String] = ["9", "10", "11"]
                            if aceSevenStand.contains(clippedDealerCurrentCard[0]) {
                                correctAnswer = "STAND"
                            } else if aceSevenHit.contains(clippedDealerCurrentCard[0]) {
                                correctAnswer = "HIT"
                            } else {
                                correctAnswer = "DOUBLE"
                            }
                        } else if (clippedYouCard1[0] == "11" || clippedYouCard2[0] == "11") && (clippedYouCard1[0] == "8" || clippedYouCard2[0] == "8") {
                            let aceEightDouble: [String] = ["6"]
                            if aceEightDouble.contains(clippedDealerCurrentCard[0]) {
                                correctAnswer = "DOUBLE"
                            } else {
                                correctAnswer = "STAND"
                            }
                        } else if (clippedYouCard1[0] == "11" || clippedYouCard2[0] == "11") && (clippedYouCard1[0] == "9" || clippedYouCard2[0] == "9") {
                            correctAnswer = "STAND"
                        } else if Int(clippedYouCard1[0])! + Int(clippedYouCard2[0])! == 5 {
                            correctAnswer = "HIT"
                        } else if Int(clippedYouCard1[0])! + Int(clippedYouCard2[0])! == 6 {
                            correctAnswer = "HIT"
                        } else if Int(clippedYouCard1[0])! + Int(clippedYouCard2[0])! == 7 {
                            correctAnswer = "HIT"
                        } else if Int(clippedYouCard1[0])! + Int(clippedYouCard2[0])! == 8 {
                            correctAnswer = "HIT"
                        } else if Int(clippedYouCard1[0])! + Int(clippedYouCard2[0])! == 9 {
                            let sumNineDouble: [String] = ["3", "4", "5", "6"]
                            if sumNineDouble.contains(clippedDealerCurrentCard[0]) {
                                correctAnswer = "DOUBLE"
                            } else {
                                correctAnswer = "HIT"
                            }
                        } else if Int(clippedYouCard1[0])! + Int(clippedYouCard2[0])! == 10 {
                            let sumTenHit: [String] = ["10", "11"]
                            if sumTenHit.contains(clippedDealerCurrentCard[0]) {
                                correctAnswer = "HIT"
                            } else {
                                correctAnswer = "DOUBLE"
                            }
                        } else if Int(clippedYouCard1[0])! + Int(clippedYouCard2[0])! == 11 {
                            correctAnswer = "DOUBLE"
                        } else if Int(clippedYouCard1[0])! + Int(clippedYouCard2[0])! == 12 {
                            let sumTwelveStay: [String] = ["4", "5", "6"]
                            if sumTwelveStay.contains(clippedDealerCurrentCard[0]) {
                                correctAnswer = "STAND"
                            } else {
                                correctAnswer = "HIT"
                            }
                        } else if Int(clippedYouCard1[0])! + Int(clippedYouCard2[0])! == 13 {
                            let sumThirteenStay: [String] = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
                            if sumThirteenStay.contains(clippedDealerCurrentCard[0]) {
                                correctAnswer = "STAND"
                            } else {
                                correctAnswer = "HIT"
                            }
                        } else if Int(clippedYouCard1[0])! + Int(clippedYouCard2[0])! == 14 {
                            let sumFourteenStay: [String] = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
                            if sumFourteenStay.contains(clippedDealerCurrentCard[0]) {
                                correctAnswer = "STAND"
                            } else {
                                correctAnswer = "HIT"
                            }
                        } else if Int(clippedYouCard1[0])! + Int(clippedYouCard2[0])! == 15 {
                            let sumFifteenStay: [String] = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
                            if sumFifteenStay.contains(clippedDealerCurrentCard[0]) {
                                correctAnswer = "STAND"
                            } else {
                                correctAnswer = "HIT"
                            }
                        } else if Int(clippedYouCard1[0])! + Int(clippedYouCard2[0])! == 16 {
                            let sumSixteenStay: [String] = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
                            if sumSixteenStay.contains(clippedDealerCurrentCard[0]) {
                                correctAnswer = "STAND"
                            } else {
                                correctAnswer = "HIT"
                            }
                        } else if Int(clippedYouCard1[0])! + Int(clippedYouCard2[0])! == 17 {
                            correctAnswer = "STAND"
                        } else if Int(clippedYouCard1[0])! + Int(clippedYouCard2[0])! == 18 {
                            correctAnswer = "STAND"
                        } else if Int(clippedYouCard1[0])! + Int(clippedYouCard2[0])! == 19 {
                            correctAnswer = "STAND"
                        }
                        

                        var randomYouCard1 = cardArray.randomElement()!
                        var randomYouCard2 = cardArray.randomElement()!
                        var randomDealerCard = cardArray.randomElement()!
                        
                        
                        

                        
                    }) {
                        ZStack {
                            Circle()
                                .frame(width: 80)
                            Text(self.standButton)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                    }
        }
```

Comment: Add an `else` block at the end of you `else if` ladder and see if that is getting called. Print your various variables inside that and see what state is causing the issue

Comment: That comment gave me some ideas to test which ultimately led to the solution. I needed to reset youAnswer to "" in order for the repeat button action to flow properly. Thank you for the push in the right direction!